# In Python, what are the data type if appending an integer to a list of strings

Tags: python, list

This is what I do:

```
>>> arr1 = ['er','t','ty']    # I suppose these three elements are strings
>>> arr1.append(3)            # try to append an integer 3
>>> print arr1
['er', 't', 'ty', 3]
```

Question: I think that arr1 is an list; 'er','t','ty' are strings; and 3 is still an integer. Is this correct? Or 3 has been automatically casted as string.

Comment: no, it's still an integer. You can store any datatype value inside a list.

Comment: There is no commitment that, elements of a list have to be of same datatype.

Comment: Thank you guys. I thought all elements have to be in the same type. This is not true in python

Answer (score 5):

`list` is a sequence of heterogeneous objects. They can be any type. You can verify this with the built-in function `type()`:

```
>>> arr1 = ['er','t','ty']
>>> arr1.append(3)
>>> print(arr1)
['er', 't', 'ty', 3]
>>> for object in arr1:
...    print(object, type(object))
...
er <class 'str'>
t <class 'str'>
ty <class 'str'>
3 <class 'int'>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Its quiet different with other languages (C, C++, etc)

Answer (score 0):

3 is still an integer. 
list can contain different type of items. 
itself has type as <class 'list'>
Unlike other languages like C++, there is not things like "integer list" or "foo list", it is just a list in python.

Comment: Actually there is a thing like "integer list": the Python `array` type. You don't often use it directly, but it is an essential underpinning to efficient manipulation of bulk *homogeneous* data in packages like `numpy`